# Create dataframe ,subset from other dataframe with extra columns having blank values.There is a lookup table for header values of both dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    id  job fname   lname
0   4   abc james   frank
1   6   cde bob     altin
2   7   kde kevin   mchon
3   8   mde george  fndes
```

I want to build the 2nd dataframe whose header values are present in the lookup table

```
    ticket  JOB_ID  virtual
0   4        abc    nan
1   5        cde    nan
2   7        kde    nan
3   8        mde    nan
```

using the lookup table for headers which is as follows

```
    Header1 Header2
0   ticket  id
1   JOB_ID  job
2   virtual
```

Note that for the second dataframe that i am building, it might happen that there wont be any corresponding header from  1 st dataframe so that column should be formed with blank values

Comment: So you just want to selectively copy columns over?

Comment: What is your best attempt?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ     yes basically I am trying to create a dataframe having columns(Header1) as one mentioned in the lookup and fill in the  values corresponding to the header values from lookup in the first dataframe(Header2 in the 1st dataframe)

Comment: @JitendraAswani In that case the answer below works. Go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rename` and `reindex`

```
In [124]: (df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('Header2')['Header1'])
              .reindex(columns=df2['Header1'].values))
Out[124]:
   ticket JOB_ID  virtual
0       4    abc      NaN
1       6    cde      NaN
2       7    kde      NaN
3       8    mde      NaN
```

---

Details

```
In [125]: df1
Out[125]:
   id  job   fname  lname
0   4  abc   james  frank
1   6  cde     bob  altin
2   7  kde   kevin  mchon
3   8  mde  george  fndes

In [126]: df2
Out[126]:
   Header1 Header2
0   ticket      id
1   JOB_ID     job
2  virtual     NaN

In [127]: df2.set_index('Header2')['Header1']
Out[127]:
Header2
id      ticket
job     JOB_ID
NaN    virtual
Name: Header1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks!!! the answer was very helpful